# Pattern synonym with "virtual" arg and conjunction

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have types:

```hs
data Some a = S1 a | S2 a

data BigRec = BigRec {
  some :: Some [Int]
  , ...
  }
```

and I want a pattern synonym that will have a "virtual argument", like

```hs
pattern BadBigRec t <- ...
```

where `t` is `True` or `False` which depends on the value of `some`: if it's `S1 something-particular` - it's `True`, else if it is `S2 something-other`, it's `False`. I hit 2 problems: I don't know how to have an "argument" in a pattern synonym which is only in the left hand side and it is not presented in the right hand side (`t` is "virtual" and it does not exist in `BigRec` or `Some`). And the second problem, I don't know how to express "OR" (conjunction) in pattern synonyms. Not just pattern that match, but a conjunct of predicates.

Is it possible with pattern synonyms or only pattern views are useful for such cases?

Comment: You can turn any pair of back-and-forth functions into a pattern synonym by using `-XViewPatterns`. But the extracting function had better be a (partial) left inverse of the injecting function, which I don't see here – but I also don't really understand what logic you want here. Elaborate by showing the behaviour with ordinary functions.

Comment: (In fact, you don't even need an injecting function at all, you can also define a matching-only pattern synonym. But in that case I'd strongly suggest not using patterns at all, but instead simply predicate functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a view pattern.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms #-}

data Some a = S1 a | S2 a

data BigRec = BigRec {
  some :: Some [Int]
  }

pattern BadBigRec :: Bool -> BigRec
pattern BadBigRec t <- (checkBad -> t)

-- modify this as needed
checkBad :: BigRec -> Bool
checkBad x = case some x of
   S1 _ -> True
   S2 _ -> False
```